# Angular Material Tabs: how to make FLEX fit not overfow

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

so this is the stackblitz demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wg8jkx

I am trying to achieve a normal header where I have
h1 title (to the left)
tabs (available width)
toolbar (to the right...

so I have this styling... quote straight forward:

```
.page-header {
  display: flex;

  .page-title {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }

  .page-tabs {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }

  .page-toolbar {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
```

and in my view I am adding tabs on the fly with something like that

```
<nav #tabNav mat-tab-nav-bar color="accent">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    {{ tab }}
  </a>
</nav>
```

The tabs overflow once I add enough tabs.... what it is suppose to show are the < and > buttons (tab pagination)...

how do I achieve this dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by specifying the following css rules:

```
.page-tabs {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

`flex: 1` is a shortcut for `flex: 1 1 0%`. The key here is to set both `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to `1`.

Only after that `overflow-x: hidden` can do the magic.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dzuiv?file=src/app/app.component.scss)**

[image]

Comment: ah man, I was so happy... it would be a life saver... seriously I spent so much time on it.... but the problem, as you can see, the tab indicator under, disappears. making this solution not acceptable. :'( to make only -x (overflow-x) hidden, does not work

Comment: What do you mean by `the tab indicator under disappears`?

Comment: nvm, was just missing a bit of code in stackblitz (for simplicity)... here, the missing bit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaqwqu

Comment: I don't see problem here. The tab indicator is always under selected tab. If you want it to be always visible then scroll to that active tab

Comment: as I said, Never mind, my bad ;) The indicator in my original was not visible, since it didn't have the "active" property on it... I set it in the last pasted  sb. ... so all good ;) Cheers

Comment: btw, how do you make localized animated gifs like the one you appended to the post?

Comment: I used GifCam to record gif from screen